# Cant wrap my head around Classes and Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to use `kivy.clock` object more specifically `Clock.schedule_interval` to take temperature readings every couple seconds.

I create a method in my main screen class (`MyTerrLayout(Screen)`) called `clockAction`. now when I type in `Clock.schedule_interval(clockAction, 2)` I get:

```
NameError: clockAction is not defined
```

So I tired to do `self.clockAction` but that didn't work either. I tried various methods to get it going like moving `Clock.schedule_interval(clockAction, 2)` to its own class but I get other errors. Do i have to create an instance of the method `clockAction`? Or since `Clock.schedule_interval(clockAction, 2)` might be a class attribute it needs to be called a different way.

Or is it because `Clock.schedule_interval(clockAction, 2)` is a class attribute that I need to call `clockAction` a different way? I can't seem to make the connection.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome. Also does anyone know where I can practice more complex examples of OOP and class manipulation? Or does someone have some old homework regarding class manipulation and OOP concepts?

Here is my code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from random import randint
from kivy.lang import Builder  
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock
import threading

Window.size = (600,250)

tep = 75
hum = 85
# Window Manager Class
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass    


# Main home menu Class
class MyTerrLayout(Screen):
    internal_read = ObjectProperty(None)
    external_read = ObjectProperty(None)
    target_temp = ObjectProperty(None)
    target_hum = ObjectProperty(None)

    Clock.schedule_interval(clockAction, 2) #Clock Schedule

    def set_temp(self):
        global tep
        self.ids._Target_Temp.text = str(tep) + " F" 

    def set_hum(self):
        global hum
        self.ids._Target_Hum.text = str(hum) + "%"
    
    def clockAction(self, dt=0): ####method I am trying to run
        self.ids.external_reading.text = str(randint(1,10))
        print('test')


# Temprature Screen Class / Window  
class TempWindow(Screen):
    def sub_temp(self):
        global tep
        tep = tep - 1
        self.temp_menu.text = str(tep)

    def add_temp(self):
        global tep
        tep = tep + 1
        self.temp_menu.text = str(tep)
    def set_temp(self):
        terrlayout = self.manager.get_screen('main') 
        terrlayout.set_temp()

class HumWindow(Screen):   
    def sub_hum(self):
        global hum
        hum = hum - 1
        self.ids.set_hum_menu.text = str(hum)

    def add_hum(self):
        global hum
        hum = hum + 1
        self.ids.set_hum_menu.text = str(hum)

    def set_temp(self):
        terrlayout = self.manager.get_screen('main') 
        terrlayout.set_hum()

class AC(Screen):

    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.Callback_Clock, 2)

    def Callback_Clock(self, dt):
        terrlayout = self.manager.get_screen('main')
        terrlayout.clockAction()
# Builder Section
kv = Builder.load_file('terrlayoutV1.kv')

class TerrLayout(App):
    def build(self):
        
        return kv


if __name__=="__main__":
    TerrLayout().run()
```

Comment: Given the error, I'm gonna say you didn't define clockAction correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
class MyTerrLayout(Screen):
    [...]
    Clock.schedule_interval(clockAction, 2)
    [...]
```

That code is in the `class` part of `MyTerrLayout`. In other languages, we call that `static`. `clockAction` has `self` as a parameter, which means it is not static.

In a static context, you can't access members of an object, because there is no object to refer to.

IMHO this should be done when the object is created:

```
def __init__(self, **kw):
    super().__init__(**kw)
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.clockAction, 2)  # Clock Schedule
```

Note that the `__init__` method has `self` and you can refer to `self.clockAction`.

Comment: This worked ! Thanks Thomas! So should I always do class instantiation with any class I make? I just saw so many kivy tutorials and examples where no one was doing this. But it seems like for best practice this would be the way. So by performing this instantiation how does that allow you to refer to other methods ? I noticed you said __init__ has self does that mean that the object self now represents the class MyTerrLayout itself? allowing you to refer to other methods like (MyTerrLayout)self.clockAction..... ? Does that sound right ?

Comment: Within any method that has `self`, you can call any other method of the same object also by `self.method_name()`

Comment: I'm not a Kivy expert. Maybe people do not use `Clock` often, so there's no need for them to get the clock working with an object. Thus the default `__init__` is sufficient for them.